# SQL Conditional filter with different values

Tags: sql

I have found lots of posts on coniditonal filtering in the where clause, but they all seem to be based off of using the same value, such as:

```
WHERE  (o.OrderID = @orderid OR @orderid IS NULL)
```

I need to do something slightly different, I need to remove a filter and its value completely base on another value, so something like:

```
select *
from tableA
where 1 = 1
case when a = 1 then
   and b in (select b from tableB)
else
  -- do nothing
end
```

I know that the above is not allowed, and I am just writing as an example of what I am trying to do.  does Anyone have any idea of a good way to do this?  I know i could use if statements and duplicate the query, but it is a large one, and i am trying to avoid that.

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The answer depends on that. Yes it is possible to use a `CASE` statement in a WHERE clause but the syntax is dependent on the flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM tableA
    WHERE a <> 1
        OR (a = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT b from TableB WHERE tableA.b = TableB.b))
```

You could also write this as:

```
SELECT tableA.*
    FROM tableA
        LEFT JOIN tableB
            ON tableA.b = tableB.b
    WHERE tableA.a <> 1
        OR (tableA.a = 1 AND tableB.b IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Correcting" your `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
  from tableA
 where 'T' = case 
                when a = 1 then case
                                   when b in (select b from tableB) then 'T'
                                end
                else 'T'
             end;
```